# PCA().fit() is using the wrong axis for data input

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, decomposition

I'm using `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` to pre-process some training data for a machine learning model. There is 247 data points with 4095 dimensions, imported from a `csv` file using `pandas`. I then scale the data

`training_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(training[:,1:4096])`

before calling the `PCA` algorithm to obtain the variance for each dimension,

`pca = PCA(n_components)`

`pca.fit(training_data)`.

The output is a vector of length 247, but it should have length 4095 so that I can work out the variance of each dimension, not the variance of each data point.

My code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

test = np.array(pd.read_csv("testing.csv", sep=','))
training = np.array(pd.read_csv("training.csv", sep=','))
# ID Number = [0]
# features = [1:4096]

training_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(training[:,1:4096])
test_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(test[:,1:4096])
training_labels = training[:,4609]

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(training_data)
pca_variance = pca.explained_variance_.
```

I have tried taking the transpose of `training_data`, but this didn't change the output. I have also tried changing `n_components` in the argument of the `PCA` function, but it is insistent that there can only be 247 dimensions.

This may be a stupid question, but I'm very new to this sort of data processing. Thank you.

Comment: Something is wrong with your data. what does `print(training_data.shape)`return ?

Comment: @seralouk That returns `(247, 4095)`.

Comment: see my answer cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> " but it should have length 4095 so that I can work out the variance of
>   each dimension, not the variance of each data point."

No. This is only true if you would estimate 4095 components using `pca = PCA(n_components=4095)`.

---

On the other hand, you define:

```
pca = PCA() # this is actually PCA(n_components=None)
```

so `n_components` is set to `None`.

---

**When this happens we have (see the [documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)):**

`n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)`

Thus, in your case, you have `min(247, 4095) = 247` components.

So, `pca.explained_variance_.` will be a vector with shape 247 since you have 247 PC dimensions.

---

**Why do we have `n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)` ?**

This is related to the rank of the covariance/correlation matrix. Having a data matrix `X` with shape `[247,4095]`, the covariance/correlation matrix would be `[4095,4095]` with max rank = min(n_samples, n_features). Thus, you have at most min(n_samples, n_features) meaningful PC components/dimensions.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thank you.